# Invalid character in name at 1; spacing to blame?

Tags: fortran

I'm debugging some Fortran code. I should note I'm not familiar with Fortran (the code was someone else's that I'm modifying for a different project). It's basically a list of chemical reaction rates for a simulation.

The rate I'm having trouble implementing is as follows:

```
  if (CHEMJ(1,J).EQ.'HNO3'.AND.CHEMJ(2,J).EQ.'OH') THEN
   A(J,I) = 2.4E-14*EXP(460./T(I))+6.5E-34 *exp(1335./T(I)) *
   ((1+6.5E-34) * EXP(-1335./T(I))/2.7E-17 *EXP(2199./T(I)))
  endif
```

However, this keeps triggering the following error:

```
  285 |    A(J,I) = 2.4E-14*EXP(460./T(I))+6.5E-34 *
      |                         1
  Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

I'm not sure why 460. is being read as invalid, though I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact the code wraps around. I've tried adding an &, but that didn't seem to help, either. Since this is legacy code, I can't easily change the file from .f to .f90, so I'm stuck with dealing with the older style of wrap-around.

Any ideas how to fix this particular bug?

Comment: The code is probably in fixed-form source format, which has restrictions of line lengths and what can appear in columns 1-6.  If the line exceeds 72 characters, then you'll need to wrap the line.  Column 6 is reserved for a continuation character, which tells the compiler the line is a continuation of the previous line.

Comment: You don't seam to mark the line continuation in any way? Is the code copied **exactly**? Pay attention to the column at the start. Please show more complete code, declare variables and tell us how you mark the line continuation. See [mcve]. Note the *reproducible*, we should be able to reproduce your error message on our computer.